# How to test windows phone 7 class library?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, windows-phone-7

Is there any way to test a Windows Phone 7 Class library? Usually (for WinForms or WPF applications) I create separate class library and add reference to nunit.framework.dll and to a class library which I want to test.

Here, if I create new Windows Phone class library it doesn’t allow me to add reference to NUnit framework assembly.

If I create usual Class library, it obviously allows me to refer to NUnit, but doesn’t allow to add reference to the Windows Phone Class library that I want to test.
Closed loop :)

Any ideas on how I can perform my unit-testing?

**UPD:** I think that there is no proper solution yet. There is one raw hand-made solution(that is not even in alpha) http://wptestlib.codeplex.com/.
UnitDriven and Silverlight Unit Test Framework **can be used unless** you want to test something **device specific**. I.e. it is impossible to refer WP7 specific assemblies in these projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Unit Driven](http://unitdriven.codeplex.com/) or the [Silverlight Unit Test Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightut).

Comment: Hi JP. THank you Unit Driven is good. BUT it doesn't provide testing engine. There is UI for tetsting in Silverlight, and with some restrictions it can be used for testing #wp7 applications. in this case we need to create web-based silverlight application, refer to class library which we want to test, write tests and run it. It works perfectly unless we use #wp7 specific classes for testing. For instance I'm using System.Device.GeoCoordinate class and I still can't add reference to it to Silverlight application.

Comment: So I need something that was originally created for #wp7 and doesn't have compatability issues.

Comment: I have try to use the Unit test but failed too,I guess that we have to wait for the Microsoft'Actions